# to remove lines in which first column contains a lower case letter

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

As the title says, I want to remove the lines from my file in which the first column contains a lowercase at any point. Say, I have a file like this:

```
Ar  MA0007.3    3051    2.62674e-220 OVER   0 OVER  0.749924    0.0797918   0.6897  0.682167    -0.0615 [13,23] 1
NR3C1   MA0113.3    3051    6.79534e-208 OVER   0 OVER  0.759705    0.0819166   0.699595    0.686309    -0.0665 [13,23] 0.269309
NR3C2   MA0727.1    3051    7.09295e-206 OVER   0 OVER  0.754749    0.0821368   0.694756    0.681845    -0.067  [13,23] 0.0756584
FOXA1   MA0148.3    3051    5.53402e-91 OVER    0 OVER  0.860904    0.0640026   0.827295    0.792912    -0.0303 [-3,7]  1
Foxa2   MA0047.2    3051    3.00085e-87 OVER    0 OVER  0.864018    0.065624    0.83031 0.796327    -0.0223 [1,11]  1
FOXP1   MA0481.2    3051    3.11057e-79 OVER    0 OVER  0.843207    0.0698783   0.809315    0.779508    -0.0375 [16,26] 1
FOXL1   MA0033.2    3051    1.60328e-77 OVER    0 OVER  0.925715    0.0677064   0.892118    0.854536    -0.1102 [-2,8]  1
FOXO6   MA0849.1    3051    8.95861e-73 OVER    0 OVER  0.892953    0.0741376   0.858344    0.824513    -0.0954 [13,23] 1
FOXK1   MA0852.2    3051    2.82502e-72 OVER    0 OVER  0.820987    0.0652885   0.790887    0.76394 -0.0325 [2,12]  1
```

What I would like it to print is :

```
NR3C1   MA0113.3    3051    6.79534e-208 OVER   0 OVER  0.759705    0.0819166   0.699595    0.686309    -0.0665 [13,23] 0.269309
NR3C2   MA0727.1    3051    7.09295e-206 OVER   0 OVER  0.754749    0.0821368   0.694756    0.681845    -0.067  [13,23] 0.0756584
FOXA1   MA0148.3    3051    5.53402e-91 OVER    0 OVER  0.860904    0.0640026   0.827295    0.792912    -0.0303 [-3,7]  1
FOXP1   MA0481.2    3051    3.11057e-79 OVER    0 OVER  0.843207    0.0698783   0.809315    0.779508    -0.0375 [16,26] 1
FOXL1   MA0033.2    3051    1.60328e-77 OVER    0 OVER  0.925715    0.0677064   0.892118    0.854536    -0.1102 [-2,8]  1
FOXO6   MA0849.1    3051    8.95861e-73 OVER    0 OVER  0.892953    0.0741376   0.858344    0.824513    -0.0954 [13,23] 1
FOXK1   MA0852.2    3051    2.82502e-72 OVER    0 OVER  0.820987    0.0652885   0.790887    0.76394 -0.0325 [2,12]  1
```

and what I am using is:

```
awk '!/[a-z]/' < file.txt
```

This somehow leaves out the following rows:

```
NR3C1   MA0113.3    3051    6.79534e-208 OVER   0 OVER  0.759705    0.0819166   0.699595    0.686309    -0.0665 [13,23] 0.269309
NR3C2   MA0727.1    3051    7.09295e-206 OVER   0 OVER  0.754749    0.0821368   0.694756    0.681845    -0.067  [13,23] 0.0756584
```

Could anyone please help me in fixing this.

TIA

Comment: In your example, the output still has a column that has a lowercase characters (`Foxa2`).

Comment: Thank you, corrected the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following `awk` may help you.

```
awk '$1!~/[a-z]/'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simply checking here if `$1`(first field) is NOT equal to `/a-z/` means small letter alphabets then mentioning no action here which will do default action, which is printing the current line.

Answer (score 1):

You need to match against only the first column using `$1 ~ /regex/`:

```
awk '!($1 ~ /[a-z]/)' file
```

or equivalently:

```
awk '$1 !~ /[a-z]/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
grep '^[^a-z]\+\s' file
```

grep is fine.

well, POSIX one: `grep '^[^a-z]\+[[:space:]]' file`

Comment: `\s` and `\+` are not standard grep features, so might not work on non-GNU greps.

Comment: @TomFenech , for space, `[:space:]` could be used. I think `\+` is BRE standard, am I wrong?

Comment: If I remember correctly the only standard way to write "one or more" is `\{1,\}` (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html does not mention `+` in the "special characters" section)

Comment: `\+` is a GNU extension to BRE. I'd write `^[^[:lower:]][^[:lower:]]*[[:space:]]`. Also, `[:space:]` is the same as `[aceps:]`, you meant `[[:space:]]`.

Comment: @BenjaminW. oh, yes, `[[ .. ]]` I meant.